# Use spaces in bat script, without quotes

Tags: batch-file

I need to run

```
start cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\sdk\bin\activate & cd d:\home\name\addon\ & cfx run"
```

The problem is that first path has spaces (`Program Files`). I can't use quotes, because they are used for full command already.

How can I use spaces in this command?

Comment: What does the single & do?

Comment: It is a separator for cmd commands.

Comment: if you can't you enquote each one separately?  e.g. start cmd.exe /k "command 1" & "command 2", then maybe you should put those commands in a separate .bat file and just run that.

Comment: No, it is only `start cmd.exe /k "command here"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Who says you can't add quotes around the exe path when the /C command is already quoted? It works fine ! :-)

```
start cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\sdk\bin\activate" & cd d:\home\name\addon\ & cfx run"
```

The outer quotes around the /C command are removed prior to execution, leaving only the quotes around your exe path. You can read about how CMD process quotes in the help. Simply type `CMD /?` or `HELP CMD` from a command prompt. It does get confusing.

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

Your command has more than 2 quotes, so option 2 is followed.

The only time the above won't work is if your exe name contains a special character like `&`, for example `this&that.exe`. That causes a problem because the exe name is not quoted when the START command is initially parsed. That can be fixed by escaping the problem character within the file name.

```
start cmd.exe /k ""this^&that.exe" & echo something else"
```

Comment: I didn't even tested this, I thought it 100% will mess everything

Answer (score 4):

You can try with the old DOS-writing style, where every path-segment has maximal 8 chars like:

```
C:\Progra~1\Mozill~1\
```

the ~1 is from the alphabetical order:

```
C:\DisIsMyDirAlpha
C:\DisIsMyDirBeta
C:\DisIsMyDirGamma
```

are these:

```
C:\DisIsM~1
C:\DisIsM~2
C:\DisIsM~3
```

Comment: That will not work if on an NTFS volume with short 8.3 names disabled. There is a simpler solution that always works: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14184116/1012053)

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes for the first path and escape them with `^`:

```
start cmd.exe /k "^"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\sdk\bin\activate^" & cd d:\home\name\addon\ & cfx run"
```

---

**EDIT:**

Concerning @dbenham 's comment:
Interesting. Escaping with `^` did work for me, although my actual command was slightly different because I tested it with the first command that came into my mind.

This works on my machine (Windows XP SP 3):

```
start cmd.exe /k "xcopy ^"C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Messenger\license.rtf^" c:\"
```

I also read about escaping using double quotes `""`, but that didn't work for me with my above example.
Then again, I'm no batch file guru and maybe `cmd.exe` behaves differently when you use `&` (which I never heard about before).

Comment: That does NOT work. Try it! If you remove the carets, as I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14184116/1012053), then it works fine.

Comment: @dbenham: Maybe it only worked for me because I used a slightly different example command. I added some information to my answer!

Comment: Your case works because you have escaped the quotes around a command option. The carets are removed by the time XCOPY reads the option. It works just as well without the carets. It does not work if you escape quotes around an executable with spaces in the name. The parser will break off the name of the exe at the first space, and it will fail. I'll grant you, batch quoting and escaping can get complicated, but this answer is barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
start cmd.exe /k "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\sdk\bin\activate & cd d:\home\name\addon\ & cfx run"
```

Add those two extra quotes before the filepath. That usually works for me.
Good luck :)

Comment: That looked rather iffy to me, so I tried it and it didn't work. I'm not even sure what those extra quotes are intended to accomplish, but it's like entering `" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\sdk\bin\activate & cd d:\home\name\addon\ & cfx run` at the prompt, which of course doesn't work. The error I get on Windows 7 either way is `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` In any case, @dbenham's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with Win 7 Home: `start cmd.exe /c "C:\RemoveDrive\RemoveDrive G:"`

I could not make Win 7 Pro run a .bat file with any space in the path or as part of the executable ("RemoveDrive :G"). So I made RunEjectG.bat to run EjectG.bat.

It's a workaround,but I could not spend more time to solve the problem.
note: the `/c` switch closes the cmd window after running the bat, a `/k` switch leaves cmd window open.